# Sometimes when entering password at login, system immediately sleeps

Tags: 18.04, suspend, power-management

Have not been able to find an answer after searching around on this one.

I have a bizarre issue where after waking from sleep and entering a user's password, the system will immediately go to sleep after hitting enter. It doesn't happen every time when logging in after sleep, but when it does system has to be restarted to be usable again.

Running a 5-year old custom build machine on Ubuntu 18.04.2. 
MSI motherboard - Z87-G43 (MS-7816)
Intel® Core™ i5-4570 CPU @ 3.20GHz × 4
AMD Cayman GPU
16GB RAM

Occasionally the system will also immediately sleep when choosing "Log in as a different user" from the login screen.